# Which characterization of continuity in a point is used here?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I am currently studying a proof, where we have a function $f: A\to Y$ where $A\subseteq X$ is a topological space, and $Y$ is a metric space.

We want to show that $f$ is continuous in a point $x$, and the proof goes along to show that for a specific open neighborhood of $f(x)$ the preimage contains an open neighborhood of $x$.

> For $\varepsilon >0$ we show that $f^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(f(x)))$ contains an open neighborhood of $x$.
> Which characterization of continuity of a point is then used here?

Do we not have to show that for EVERY open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, the preimage contains an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$.

A function $f:X\to Y$ of topological spaces is continuous in $x$ if the preimage of neighborhoods of $f(x)$ or neighborhoods of $x$.

But in the given proof it looks like that for a general type of open neighborhoods this is shown.
So to general in my opinion.

Or is this just an equivalent characterization that I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have indeed proved that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $f^{-1}\bigl(B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Now, let $V$ be *any* neighborhood of $f(x)$. Then, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\subset V$ and therefore $f^{-1}\bigl(B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)\subset f^{-1}(V)$. Since $f^{-1}\bigl(B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then so is $f^{-1}(V)$.